# Execute Jar: Main class cannot be loaded or found

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

I'm trying to build an executable jar file out of my project.
Since it's a Maven project, I'm trying to achieve it like this:

```
./mvnw package -Pdev -DskipTests
```

I get a jarfile out of that, so until here it's working fine. However, when I want to execute the jarfile with:

```
java -jar myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I get an error that the main class cannot be loaded or found. 
I have already googled this issue and added the following lines to my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.david.coinlender.CoinlenderApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have stated my mainClass package and class name, however, that doesn't help.
What I assume the problem could be: Inside the jar file there's a folder classes (with the compiled classes).
Do I need to somehow add a property `classpathPrefix` for the classes? I only use it for the libs so far.

Can anyone please help me?

Kind regards,
David

@Update:
When I open the JAR file, I see a completely different structure than my app structure. Let me post a screenshot of what I see:
[image: folder structure of the JAR file]

Could there be a problem with building the JAR file?

Comment: Can you show CoinlenderApp?

Comment: As suggested by @markusk, try removing `addClasspath` and `classPathPrefix`. This should work for you. If possible, please add output of `jar tf target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I remove addClasspath and classPathPrefix it throws the same error.

The jar tf command gives me a huge list of files. What part is relevant for you to get more information?

Answer (score 0):

`addClassPath` and `classPathPrefix` are for referencing local class or JAR files that exist outside the JAR file. These directives aren't needed for referencing a class that is contained in the JAR file already.

It sounds very strange that there's a folder `classes` in your JAR file. The class files should be directly at the top level, e.g.

```
$ jar tf myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/david/
com/david/coinlender/
com/david/coinlender/CoinLenderApp.class
```

It sounds like your project isn't following the [Maven standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), causing the class files to be stored in the wrong location. Could this be the cause of your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I gave you the wrong information. classes folder is in target (so outside of the jar, not IN the jar). When I execue **jar tf <name>.jar** it displays a whole list of filenames. Which information do you need in order to get a better overview?

Comment: What's the output from `jar tf <name>.jar | grep -i coinlender`?

Comment: Just tried ´jar tf .\coinlender-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep -i coinlender´, it returns an empty result

Comment: Then the `CoinlenderApp` class doesn't exist in the JAR file, and that's why Java can't find it. Do you have a file `src/java/main/com/david/coinlender/CoinlenderApp.java` in your project? Might there be a typo somewhere?

Comment: The strange thing is that when I open the jar file, I see a completely different app structure. I post a screenshot of what I see inside the folder. Maybe there might be an issue with building the jar file?

Comment: It's hard to tell just from the information you have provided. Could you please post the directory structure of your project (e.g., by running `tree` from the command line), as well as your entire `pom.xml` file?